# Interpret Coefficient of Determination in matrix form

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, covariance-matrix, r-squared

In matrix form, a linear regression can be represented in the following form:
$$
Y \sim \mathbf{X} \beta + \epsilon; \\
\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})
$$

The definition of $R^2$ is the proportion of variance of $Y$ explained by the independent variable of $\mathbf{X}$, or $$
R^2 = \frac{Var(\mathbf{X\beta})}{Var(Y)}
$$.

I feel confused to think about terms like $Var(Y)$: since $Y$ is a random vector, wouldn’t the variance of a random vector be a **matrix**?

However, it's obvious that both the denominator and the numerator should be a scaler. How should I interpret this?

Comment: So, $R^2$ (for fixed $x$) is nothing but the proportion of total sum of squares due to regression, that is $$R^2:=\frac{\text{SSR}}{\text{SST}} = \frac{\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}^\prime\mathbf X^\prime\mathbf y -n\bar y^2}{\mathbf{y^\prime y} -n\bar y^2}.$$ This can be expressed in terms of sample variances, covariances as $$\frac{\mathbf{s}^\prime_{yx}\mathbf S^{-1}_{xx}\mathbf{s}_{yx}}{s_{yy}}.$$ Now, could you tell which part of the expression is bothering you?

Comment: In your setup, $R^2$ is defined as in the comment by @User1865345. If $(X,Y)$ is a random vector where $Y$ is response and $X$ is covariate, we use a model like $Y=\phi(X)+\epsilon$. Here $Y$ is a scalar, $X$ could be a vector but $\phi$ is again real-valued. Then we have $R^2=\operatorname{Var}(\phi(X))/\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

Comment: In fact $\phi$ is linear in $X$ in my last comment.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am a bit confused about how to interpret this: I think what you mean is $Var(\phi(X)) = Var(X_i \beta)$. However, covariate $X$ is fixed in the setting of linear regression. I am not sure how to interpret the variance of a fixed term. I have the same confusion when I saw $\hat \beta = \frac{Cov(x, y)}{Var(x)}$. I can only interpret the variance of a random variable.